# How to limit parameter values for a function that resides on a parameter that you are passing to a function

Tags: typescript

** Sorry for the long format, but I hope it helps communicate my issue/need **

We currently have an interface that allows one to pick a value out of a bunch of data that was imported from a flat file, it looks something like this:

```js
class CustomerData {
  getFieldValue(fieldName: string): string {...}
}
```

When invoking the function, the convention is to use an enum called `CustomerFieldName` as the value for the `fieldName` parameter.  The `enum` is huge and looks something like this

```js
enum CustomerFieldName {
  CUST_ID = '1',
  CUST_NAME = '2',
  CUST_PH_HOME = '3-1',
  // ect..
}
```

Notice that the `fieldName` param on `getFieldValue` is typed as `string`, we're just using the `CustomerFieldName` enum as a glorified `const` bucket for when we call the function. I could pass in `FOO_BAR` as a value to `getFieldName` and it won't reject it (but it probably wouldn't find a value in `CustomerData`).

The problem is, we've gotten into the habit of just passing this big blob of `CustomerData` around to a bunch of functions. This is a legacy code base so I don't want to go nuts refactoring the internals of it, but from a caller's perspective, we don't know what actual `fieldName`s will be used with `getFieldValue` internally when the function uses the `CustomerData` parameter. Makes it hard to test a function that accept a `CustomerData` type because we just don't really know what to mock.

Again, I don't want to change the underlying semantics w.r.t. how functions will interact with this `CustomerData` object (i.e. let them continue to use `getFieldValue('...')`) however what I would like to do is give the caller some confidence on exactly which `CustomerFieldName` values will be used by the function that they are calling.

For example: If I have a function called `prepareCustomerInvoice(custData: CustomerData)` which is going to call `custData.getFieldValue('2')` and `custData.getFieldValue('3-1')` but no others, then I'd like to communicate this fact back to a the caller via the function signature by changing the type of `custData` parameter to *something like*:

```js
type CustomerInvoiceArgs = CustomerData & {
  getFieldValue(fieldName: CustomerFieldName.CUST_ID | CustomerFieldName.CUST_PH_HOME)
}
```

Then we'd change the method signature of `prepareCustomerInvoice` to:

`prepareCustomerInvoice(custData: CustomerInvoiceArgs)`

and anywhere within `prepareCustomerInvoice` when someone introduces some code that might call `custData.getFieldValue('NOT_1_OR-3-1')` a nice compile error would occur (i.e. IDE red-squiggles).

So, I'd like to keep the calling semantics the same (i.e. let us continue to just pass in a variable of type `CustomerData`) but internally the function that the instance was passed to would be limited in which field names it use with`enter code here` that instance's `getFieldValue` method.

I hope this all makes sense.

**Edit**

CRice gave a good hint in the comments; I have to Omit `getFieldValue` before I redfine it. However I ran into another snag:

```js
enum CustomerFieldName {
  CUST_ID = '1',
  CUST_NAME = '2',
  CUST_PH_HOME = '3-1',
  // ect..
}

class CustomerData {
  getFieldValue(fieldName: string): string { return fieldName }
}

type OnlyTheseFields = `${CustomerFieldName.CUST_ID | CustomerFieldName.CUST_PH_HOME}`
type LimitedFieldCustomerData<T> = Omit<CustomerData, 'getFieldValue'> & {
  getFieldValue: (index: T) => string
}

function bar(custData: CustomerData) {
  custData.getFieldValue(CustomerFieldName.CUST_NAME);
}

function foo(custData: LimitedFieldCustomerData<OnlyTheseFields>) {
  custData.getFieldValue(CustomerFieldName.CUST_NAME); // great this doesn't compile!
  bar(custData); // boo this compiles fine but inside bar its using a a field that `getFieldValue` shouldn't support
;}
```

As you can see, the functionality works perfectly in `foo` in that it complains that I can't use `CUST_NAME` as a valid parameter to `getFieldValue`. However if I pass along this "Limited" version of `CustomerData` to `bar`, I would have expected this to have complained at the invocation site because that the `custData` that I'm passing bar isn't what it needs.

Comment: If you intend to override the type for the `getFieldValue` function, you need to omit it from `CustomerData` and then intersect with the type that holds the new signature. IE: `type CustomerInvoiceArgs = Omit<CustomerData, "getFieldValue"> & {...}`. Doing so seems to get you the errors you want inside the `prepareCustomerInvoice` function. See [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/W4PlBW). If that works for you, I can try to write that as an answer; if not, what about that doesn't work for you and I can try to modify.

Comment: @CRice ahh of course! I'll play around with that.

Comment: @CRice this worked great, I have a solution now. I had to add one special thing in that I had to create a "Template Literal Type" and after omitting `getFieldValue` for when I redfine that function. I changed it's input param type to be:

type OnlyFieldsWeWant = `${CustomerFieldName.CUST_ID | CustomerFieldName.CUST_PH_HOME}`

Comment: @CRice I have updated my question with an edit, if you have any ideas please chime in!

Comment: I'm not sure on the new issue. It seems like it may be a bug in TS to me. Typescript normally wouldn't allow that assignment since the function signatures of `getFieldValue` aren't compatible. And indeed we see this when they are written out explicitly, but the same doesn't occur for the inferred types... See [the playground here](https://tsplay.dev/wjnYYw).